# Using jQuery to change div width from 50% to 70% on hover

Tags: jquery, html, width, jquery-animate

I have two divs that have 50% width each. I want to make it so that the the hovered div expands to 70% and the other reduces to 30%. And when the mouse moves out, they both return to 50% each. I wrote a script but it doesn't give the right results. The widths are fluid so they need to adjust to all window sizes. how Can I make this work right?

I didn't write the mouseout function yet as the mouseover doesn't function correctly.

Here's how it works now:
http://jsfiddle.net/kYZyp/

Here's my code:

```
<div id="left" class="content_left"></div>
<div id="right" class="content_right"></div>
```

Here's my css for the div's

```
.content_left {
    width:50%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:url(wedding.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity:0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.content_right {
    width:50%;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:url(events.jpg) right center no-repeat;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity:0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

And i'm using this script:

```
<script>
$("#left").mouseover(function(){
  $("#left").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500 );
  $("#right").animate({
    width: "30%"
  }, 1500 );
});

$("#right").mouseover(function(){
  $("#right").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500 );
  $("#left").animate({
    width: "30%"
  }, 1500 );
});

</script>
```

And including this jQuery file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7rc2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't know if this suites you: http://jsfiddle.net/yCY9y/3/

DOM:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" class="content_left">LEFT</div><div id="right" class="content_right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

I use the wrapper to be sure we never break the RIGHT to the next line.

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#left, #right {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
#left {
    background:red;
}
#right {
    background:yellow;
}
```

I use on `#wrapper`

```
white-space:nowrap; // Newer break whitespaces (break to the next line)
```

and

```
width:100%;
```

On `#left, #right` we use:

```
display:inline-block;
```

witch is first compatible with >IE6. (hopes this is not a problem).

JS:

```
$("#left, #right").each(function() {
    $(this).data("standardWidth", $(this).width());
});

$("#left, #right").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "70%"
    }, 300 );
    $(this).parent().children().not(this).animate({
        width: "30%"
    }, 300 );
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().children().each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: $(this).data("standardWidth")
        }, 300 );
    });
});
```

First i Bind the same `mouseover` and `mouseout` event on both `#right` and `#left`

```
$(selector).hover(mouseOverHandler, mouseOutHandler);
```

...

```
$(this).parent().children().not(this)
```

We take the element the event is fired throw and finds all it's parents (`#wrapper`) childNodes: `$(this).parent().children()` Now we filter out everything matching `this` using jQuery's `not` method. (`this` = `#left` OR `#right`) witch is the element. Now we have `#right -> #left` and `#left -> #right`.

The `mouseOutHandler` resets all of `#wrapper` childNodes's width to 50%

Hopes this leads you the right way...

**EDIT:**

If you are expiring your animation to chain / queue up use can use the `stop` method witch stop all active animations and clears the queue:

```
$(selector).stop().animate({
    ....
})
```

Comment: That works like I want my script to. but the problem arises because I have no defined widths. I want it to be a fluid layout. How can I get the widths and use them to animate accordingly?

Comment: Okay I got your code to work for me. But I just need to know how I can make the div's height to be 100% at all times? I want it to be fluid, so the height fills up the window

Answer (score 2):

This should work nicely for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#div1").hover(
            function(){
               $(this).css("width", "70%"); 
            },
            function(){
                $(this).css("width", "50%");
            }
        );                             
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: Added animation
**EDIT**: Added height resize to animation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#div1").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).animate({ "width" : "70%", "height" : $("#container").height() + "px" }); 
            },
            function(){
                $(this).animate({ "width" : "50%", "height" : "" });
            }
        );                             
    });
</script>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid #000;padding:10px;">
    <div id="div1" style="width:50%;border:1px solid #000;min-height:100px;">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: If you want it to fill the height of the window, just use `window.innerHeight` in place of the container height:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#div1").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).animate({ "width" : "70%", "height" : window.innerHeight + "px" }); 
            },
            function(){
                $(this).animate({ "width" : "50%", "height" : "" });
            }
        );                             
    });
</script>
<div id="div1" style="width:50%;border:1px solid #000;min-height:100px;">
    Hello world!
</div>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4FcV/3/) that demonstrates it working.

Comment: Than you for the response, but I want it to have a smooth animation and I want to use JQuery for it.

Comment: Shamelessly copied your code and added animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003137/using-jquery-to-change-div-width-from-50-to-70-on-hover/8003364#8003364

Comment: That is the effect that I want, but it doesn't work in my scenario. I think it's because I do not have any defined widths, because I want the layout to be fluid. Maybe use JS to get the current width of the div and animate accordingly?

Comment: I thought you were using a percentage width though?

Comment: And I also want it to have 100% height. So it fills up the window

Comment: Yes I figured that part out. I just don't know how to make it 100% height now

Comment: James, I really appreciate the effort. But you're not understanding. Here is the jsfiddle, if you could just fix this so it works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/kYZyp/

Comment: How am I not understanding? You said that you wanted it to fill the height of the container. That container can be an element, the body, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

To take [@James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003137/using-jquery-to-change-div-width-from-50-to-70-on-hover/8003316#8003316) (+1) and add animation, just use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#div1").hover(
        function(){
           $(this).animate({width: '70%'});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({width: '50%'});
        }
    );                            
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sAW2c/