# Make a Div Up and Down on Hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I make a div move up and down on hover as if it were jumping? Would this be possible to do or can it only move up when the mouse is over the div?

Comment: CSS3 Animations ~might~ help... hard to say without more detail in your question.

Comment: You can do what you want with your div with any triggering event. Just write for example an `animate(object div)` function, moving your div as you want, and call it in your div `onMouseOver=animate(this)`.

Comment: I think you can do it using JQuery or JavaScript. use JQuery mouseover() and in a call back function add a class to the spesific div, in CSS add margin to the class you added...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003137/using-jquery-to-change-div-width-from-50-to-70-on-hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQueryUI's bounce effect for this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

You can use your hover event to trigger the effect.

i.e. something like:

```
$( "#myDIV" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).effect('bounce', {}, 'fast');
});
```

A **demo** with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/cKqsC/