# jQuery animation for a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to find some info how to make "share" button like [here](http://www.wooplr.com/look/5857891554951168). I have found that it is possible to make so many effects on buttons, but I have no idea how this effect is called and how to make this. If you have any info about this button effect, it will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple approach Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1ccyn/gyu2s2ae/

```
$("#left").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'100%'});
        $("#right").animate({width:'0%'});
    })
    $("#right").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'100%'});
        $("#left").animate({width:'0%'});
    })
    $("#left").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'50%'});
        $("#right").animate({width:'50%'});
    })
    $("#right").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'50%'});
        $("#left").animate({width:'50%'});
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I did made some changes on answer from dev-null, please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8003361/5887755

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yCY9y/1251/

```
$("#left, #right").each(function() {
  $(this).data("standardWidth", $(this).width());
});

$("#left, #right").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, 300 );
  $(this).parent().children().not(this).stop(true, false).animate({
    width: "0%"

  }, 300 );
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().children().each(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: $(this).data("standardWidth")
    }, 300 );
  });
});
```

Update: I did put .`stop(true, false)` for better result.